# Mathematica 12 books (version 12)

Tags: version-12

I have just visited https://www.wolfram.com/books/index.cgi to search for Mathematica related books. For the time being are there any books written or being under preparation that cover the new version 12?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dimitris,

The following books will be coming out shortly (in the US):

- Analysis With Mathematica, Oct 10, 2019.
- Using Mathematica for Quantum Mechanics: A Student’s Manual, Jul 26, 2019.
- The Student's Introduction to Mathematica and the Wolfram Language, Jun 29, 2019.